# NaCl support in the Everscale compiler api

Tags: solidity, everscale

I wonder if there is NaCl support in smart contracts? It doesn't matter which compiler, Solidity, cpp and etc.

Comment: Please clarify, do you mean to compile using NaCl or run smart contracts on NaCl?
I'm assuming you mean Google Natice Client. Or do you mean Networking and Cryptography library?

Comment: Please give more information, it is not clear what NaCl is and what features you need to support.